# C++ Access float pointer inside a class -> Access violation

Tags: c++, class, access-violation

Visual C++, Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express:

Access from this malloc works:

```
float* block  = (float *)_aligned_malloc(32 * sizeof(float), CACHE_ALIGNMENT);
block[0] = (float)30;  // I work fine.
```

---

But when it is inside this class, it does not work:

```
class Test
{
    private:
        //static const int numberOfElements = 1024;

    public:
        float* block1;
        float* block2;

    // Constructor
        Test::Test(int nElements)
        {
            float* block1 = (float *)_aligned_malloc(nElements * sizeof(float), CACHE_ALIGNMENT);
            float* block2 = (float *)_aligned_malloc(nElements * sizeof(float), CACHE_ALIGNMENT);
        }
    // Destructor
        Test::~Test(void) 
        {
            _aligned_free(block1);
            _aligned_free(block2);
        }
};

...

Test testClass = Test(32); 
testClass.block1[0] = (float)30;  // Access violation!

...
```

Or if declared as a pointer, the same thing (this is how I first tried it):

```
Test* testClass = new Test(32);
testClass.block1[0] = (float)30;  // Access violation!
```

---

What am I doing wrong in terms of accessing the values when the float* is define inside a class? Is the problem something else?

Comment: For god's sake, use `std::vector<float>` instead of `float *`

Comment: @sad_man, not sure if God's that concerned with the issue at hand.

Comment: If you really must try to manage memory yourself, always remember the [Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three). Although that's only one of the errors here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You assign to the variables local to constructor, not member variables. Try something like

```
    Test::Test(int nElements)
    {
        block1 = (float *)_aligned_malloc(nElements * sizeof(float), CACHE_ALIGNMENT);
        block2 = (float *)_aligned_malloc(nElements * sizeof(float), CACHE_ALIGNMENT);
    }
```

and check the values to make sure allocation succeeded.

Comment: @PlasmaHH true, there should be a warning about shadowing member.

Comment: Or more broad (depending on the compiler) "set but not used variable"

Comment: @PlasmaHH, both apply indeed.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I fixed this previously but for some reason missed it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The declarations of the variables `block1` and `block2` local to the constructor shadow the member variables `block1` and `block2`.

With `g++` you can get a warning for this with `-Wshadow` option. With Visual Studio I'm afraid there is no option to warn when a variable shadows another one.

Comment: Yes you are also correct, I did not have warning level 4 set (warning of unused variables). Thank you.